# OpenCart seo_url remove product_id from url

Tags: url, seo, opencart

My OpenCart store `url = http://localhost/Casual?product_id=83983` 
I am using `seo_url`, I want to make my url look like `url = http://localhost/83983`.

I tried replacing `$url .= '/' .$query->row['keyword'];`
with `$url = '/' .$query->row['keyword'];` but it is not helping me achieve my desired url. I would be glad to have some help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your product and in the Data tab, add this:

[image]

You'll also need to enable SEO URLs in System Settings and rename your .htaccess.txt to .htaccess if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thanks, it helped
I had a product name in SEO URL field, so it was not reachable.But still my URL = http://localhost/Casual/83983, I want to make it look like http://localhost/83983

Comment: It sounds like your OpenCart install is in a folder called "Casual"? In that case just move it out of that folder.